# React.js material-ui select field value isn't updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a material-ui TextField as a dropdown with a dynamically generated list. I use it in two different scenarios.

- One works - returning a single values to an array.
- One does not work - returning objects with two values {value, ID} to an array.

Codesandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-wssrp

The data in both are getting returned correctly so that's not an issue. The problem is that the selected value in the dropdown isn't updating in the one that's returning an object.

Here is the one that isn't working:

```
const [boards, setBoards] = useState([]);

let getBoards = () => {
  const client = new GraphQLClient(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: access_token,
    },
  })

const query = `{
    boards() {
        id
        name
        owner {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}`

client.request(query)
  .then(data => {
    setBoards(data.boards.map(board => {
      ////////// RETURN OBJECT WITH 2 VALUES TO THE boards array ///////////
      return {
        id: board.id,
        name: board.name
      }
    }));
  })
}

const handleBoardChange = (e) => {
  setProfile({ type: 'UPDATE_MONDAY_BOARD_NAME', value: e.target.value.name });
}

return (
  <TextField
    select
    value={profile.mondayBoardName}  ////// THIS ISN'T UPDATING /////
    onClick={getBoards}
    onChange={e => handleBoardChange(e)}
  >
    {boards.map((board, index) =>
      <MenuItem
        key={index}
        value={{ name: board.name, id: board.id }}  //// USE BOTH VALUES
      >
        {board.name}
      </MenuItem>
    )}
  </TextField>
);
```

Here is the one that does work:

```
const [sheets, setSheets] = useState([]);

let getSheets = () => {
  fetch(endpoint).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {

      ////////// RETURN OBJECT WITH 1 VALUE TO THE sheets array ///////////
      setSheets(data.sheets.map(sheet => sheet.properties.title));
  });
}

const handleSheetChange = (e) => {
  setProfile({type:'UPDATE_GS_SHEET_NAME',value: e.target.value});
}

return (
  <TextField
    className={props.classes.textField}
    value={profile.gsheetName}    ////// THIS IS UPDATING /////
    onClick={getSheets}
    onChange={e => handleSheetChange(e)}
  >
    {sheets.map((value, index) =>
      <MenuItem 
        key={index} 
        value={value}  // USE SINGLE VALUE
      >
          {value}
      </MenuItem>
    )}
  </TextField>
```

);

Comment: Can you create codesandbox reproducing your issue??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan -  Here it is...  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-wssrp